# Animating a series of PNG images in a-frame / AR.JS

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I am currently experimenting with A-Frame and AR.js for a project I'm working on. I was wondering if it's possible to animate a series of PNG files eg. `img-1.png, img-2.png`, and so on in a-frame without individually adding animation for each frame?

I'm aware of an [A-frame GIF component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-component) but GIFs are harder to maintain and can only output limited colors (and also trouble with opacity).

Any insights/help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a component, which loads up the `.png`s as textures, and swaps them in a fixed interval:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("slideshow", {
   init: function() {
```

load up and store the images

```
   var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
   this.array = []
   this.array.push(loader.load("one.png"))
   this.array.push(loader.load("two.png"))
```

Instead of doing this one by one, you could do this in a loop ("img-" + i + ".png").
Also you could provide a list using the schema.

Wait until the entity is loaded:

```
   this.el.addEventListener('loaded', e => {
       let mesh = this.getObject3D('mesh')
       let material = mesh.material
```

swap the `material.map` texture in the `tick()` or within an interval:

```
       let i = 0
       setInterval(e => {
          // if we're at the last element - swap to the first one
          if (i >= this.array.length) i = 0
          this.material.map = this.array[i++]
          this.material.needsUpdate = true
```

and it should be working like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwtzjnk9/1/), when attached to an entity:

```
<a-box slideshow></a-box>
```

---

- Why `this.array` ? For example you can easily access it in the `remove()` function and dispose the textures to free up memory.
- Why not just do `setAttribute('material', 'src', 'img-' + i + '.png')` ?
  I believe with more images it may by highly inefficcient.