# A-frame png sequences texture animation preloader?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, ar.js

I've accomplished my goal using PNG sequence for texture animation on `<a-plane>` to create 2d animation with ARJS according to answer on this question [Animating a series of PNG images in a-frame / AR.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113667/animating-a-series-of-png-images-in-a-frame-ar-js).

But there was a new problem with image loading...

Those PNG sequences consist of at least 50 frames(files) per component and there's 8 of them.
When I tried with Wi-Fi, it went well on image loading (All frames are displaying). But when I tried with Mobile Network, some frames of some objects didn't load and it will not load again.

I tried using preload function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060050/1784870) to append `<img>` to body and load texture into global array for each object, but the problem is still the same, so I ditched this solution as it won't work.

Here's the code for each component (other 7 components are the same code with different component/src name)

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("anim1", {
        init: function () {
            // load the .pngs
            let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            this.pngArray = [];
            let anim1_frames = 51; // total frames
            for (var i = 0; i < anim1_frames; i++) {
                if (i < 10) {
                    i = '0' + i; // add 0 in front of single digit frames
                }
                this.pngArray.push(loader.load('anim1/anim1' + i + '.png')); // push TextureLoader loaded with img to array
            };

            let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
            this.material = mesh.material;
            var i = 0;
            this.id = setInterval(e => {
                if (i >= this.pngArray.length) i = 0;
                this.material.map = this.pngArray[i++];
                this.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }, 1000 / 25); // play at 25fps
        },
        remove: function () {
            clearInterval(this.id);
            // free the memory
            for (let i = 0; i < this.pngArray.length; i++) {
                this.pngArray[i].dispose();
            }
        }
    })
```

What I need right now is to improve images preloading to display all frames with mobile network.

Thank you in advance

Comment: regarding the `anim1` component - existing images won't load entirely? Or it just takes too long? Also maybe you should have a set of scaled down images for mobile use?

Comment: btw if you pass the directory in the [`schema`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-properties-with-the-schema) you could do all 8 with one component :)

Comment: I will try scale down image too. Thanks for pointing out schema, I will look into it.

Comment: It took too long to load sometimes and sometimes it's fast but some frame missing.